Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1 .8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
Hello everyone i have an issue when i try to build the apk for flutter app, i have this error in my terminal :

Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1
.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

for the detail i put my code below :
 flutter version : 3.19.1
// android/build.gradle
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


// android/app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.edupass_mobile"
    compileSdk 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.edupass_mobile"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}



// settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
}

include ":app"



i have search the same problem like mine but in my code i don't have the buildscript code like the others, so i confused how to change the gradle version
can anyone help me to find the solution of this problem ?

What Flutter version are you using? Also, you specify the Kotlin compiler version to be 1.8.0

my flutter version is 3.19.1

did you try downgrading the Kotlin compiler version to 1.6.0?

how to downgrade the kotlin compiler version ? i am a beginner by the way, i am still confused how to change the version of kotlin compiler in flutter

Inside your settings.gradle file, you have this line: id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false. Change the version to "1.6.0".

i have try to change it but the error is still occur

Even if Downgrading your kotlin version works, is not a good solution in the long term, your app will not evolve and will get stuck in the past version.
The Error Explained:
When you see an error like this Is obvious that the module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. Because the binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, and the expected version is 1.6.0.
This is most likely what's happening:

Kotlin Version Mismatch: Your project or one of its dependencies was compiled with Kotlin version 1.8.0, but your current setup is expecting 1.6.0.
Binary Incompatibility: Kotlin, like any language, evolves. Changes in the language can lead to changes in how code is compiled into bytecode. When you mix different versions, the compiler gets confused because it's trying to read bytecode that it doesn't fully understand.

The posibilities of why this Happens:

Dependency Issues: One of your libraries or modules might have been compiled with a newer version of Kotlin than what your project is set to use.
Project Configuration: Your project's Kotlin version in the build.gradle might not match the versions used by your dependencies.
Recent Updates: If you've recently updated Kotlin or any libraries, but not all parts of your project, you might end up with this mismatch.
Plugins Incompatibility: some of the added plugins are not compatible with the kotlin version plugin, so yo will need to use the new version.

How to Fix It:
Unify Kotlin Versions:
Ensure all parts of your project use the same Kotlin version. Update your build.gradle to use the latest version that all your dependencies support:
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0"
}

Check Dependencies:
Use tools like gradle dependencies or gradle --info to see which dependencies are using which Kotlin version.
Force Version: If a library insists on using an older version, you might need to force the version you can add this:
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0'
}

Clean and Rebuild: Sometimes, a simple clean and rebuild can resolve issues where old bytecode lingers.
Check for Conflicts: Look for any plugins or other configurations that might be forcing a specific Kotlin version.
If you follow all the above you wont need to downgrade your Kotlin Version, in fact if you can update your kotlin version the latest working nice is version 1.9.24

thank you for answering, your answer is a reference for me and enlightens my thoughts soi can analyze what is wrong with my code, and i find the error is in the gradle version :), i will share the detail to explain it in my answer block below

**You need to write this on the build.gradle file in main folder's gradle **
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0' 
    ...
}


thank you for answering, i have try the solution but the error is still occur :(

i want to ask should i run the app in the emulator to update the app after changing the version of the kotlin or i just need to run flutter  build apk in the terminal ?

You can take a look at the Java and Gradle compatibility matrix here and the Kotlin and Kotlin plugin version as well
Based on that, you should update your JVM version to be atleast 17, since your Android Gradle Plugin in 7.3
So change the following lines
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }


thank you for answering, i have try the solution but the error is still occur :(

i want to ask should i run the app in the emulator to update the app after changing the version of the kotlin or i just need to run flutter  build apk in the terminal ?

Anything should work fine
